# Filtrar los 10 valores mayores de una columna de un DF en R

Tags: r, dataframe, filtro

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente problema:

"Cuenta el numero de casos positivos agrupado por estado y realiza una grafica de barras de los 10 estados con mas casos"

Así que filtro los datos (donde 1 significa positivo, 0 negativo)

```
Cotagiados_por_estado <- Muestra_covid %>% filter(CLASIFICACION_FINAL == 1) 
Cotagiados_por_estado %>%
  group_by(ENTIDAD_UM) %>% 
  summarise(conteo = n())
```

Pero para graficar aun no se como filtrar los 10 datos mayores. Se me ocurre hacerlo "manualmente", del resultado escoger los 10 mayores, meterlos en un vector y graficarlos o encontrar el umbral donde inician los 10 mas grandes y filtrarlos con un > Pero siento que son malas practicas. Debe existir una forma más automatizada de hacerla

Les agradezco de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vas muy bien, sólo te falta ordenar por número de casos (`arrange`) y graficar (`ggplot`):

```
library(ggplot2)

Cotagiados_por_estado %>%
  group_by(ENTIDAD_UM) %>% 
  summarise(conteo = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(desc(conteo)) %>%
  .[1:10,] %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(1:10),
             y = conteo,
             fill = ENTIDAD_UM)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  xlab('Estados con más casos') +
  ylab('Casos')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 3):

La función `tidyr::slice_max()` hace justo eso en un paso. Lo único ten en cuenta la opción `with_ties`, si hay empates en la variable `conteo` te podría sacar mas de 10 valores:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Dataset de ejemplo
set.seed(1234)
Muestra_covid <- data.frame(CLASIFICACION_FINAL = sample(c(1,2),
                                                         100000,
                                                         replace = TRUE),
                            ENTIDAD_UM = sample(letters[1:20], 100000,
                                                  replace = TRUE))

Cotagiados_por_estado <- Muestra_covid %>% filter(CLASIFICACION_FINAL == 1) 


Cotagiados_por_estado %>%
  group_by(ENTIDAD_UM) %>% 
  summarise(conteo = n())
#> # A tibble: 20 x 2
#>    ENTIDAD_UM conteo
#>    <chr>       <int>
#>  1 a            2610
#>  2 b            2483
#>  3 c            2440
#>  4 d            2524
#>  5 e            2464
#>  6 f            2533
#>  7 g            2378
#>  8 h            2522
#>  9 i            2509
#> 10 j            2477
#> 11 k            2476
#> 12 l            2476
#> 13 m            2579
#> 14 n            2429
#> 15 o            2463
#> 16 p            2507
#> 17 q            2497
#> 18 r            2561
#> 19 s            2426
#> 20 t            2482

# Con slice_max
Cotagiados_por_estado %>%
  group_by(ENTIDAD_UM) %>% 
  summarise(conteo = n()) %>%
  slice_max(n=10, order_by = conteo, with_ties = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    ENTIDAD_UM conteo
#>    <chr>       <int>
#>  1 a            2610
#>  2 m            2579
#>  3 r            2561
#>  4 f            2533
#>  5 d            2524
#>  6 h            2522
#>  7 i            2509
#>  8 p            2507
#>  9 q            2497
#> 10 b            2483
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>